# How can I add a description to each Windows wallpaper?

Tags: windows, desktop-customization

I'm running Windows 7 and have set about 35 wallpapers to change every 30 min.
I would like to see a description (eg "Thunderstorm over Uluru, Dec 2009") of each wallpaper either on the wallpaper (eg bottom-right corner) or available as a right-click.
I understand I can add text using a graphic editor such as Photoshop or Paint, but would prefer a more convenient solution eg is it possible to overlay the wallpaper with a description file?
Any suggestions?

Also, do the wallpapers change methodically? eg if waterfall.bmp follows bird15.jpg, will it always follow bird15.jpg?